# App behaves different after exit and re-enter

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova, lifecycle

**Cordova, Version 3.5.0-0.2.6**

```
<body><script> 
     alert("documentready");
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
             alert("deviceready");
          }, false);
 </script></body>
```

I enter the app after deploying, I get 'documentready' and 'deviceready' alerted.
I  leave the app with the  back button.
I get 'documentready' only.
When I force-close the app with the taskmanager or re-deploy it, I get both alerts.

I want this behaviour to occur also after normal re-entering the app.

---

I would prefer a solution where there is no evidence left that the app has  been opened before, after I leave it. Nothing restored from garbage collection etc. Ideally executing the same log as the force-close method from the task manager.

---

OK: I want, when I **close my app via back button**, that exactly **the same** happens, as when I **open the task manager and force my app to close**. Is this at least theoretically possible?

Alternatively, I would like the app, when left via back-button, to be in a 'hibernate-like' state, that if I re-enter it it behaves absolutely like it has never  been left (call **same logic as when the menu/home button is pressed**).

---

**QUESTION STILL OPEN - 50RS BOUNTY TO EARN**

Comment: Looks like http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready the event will run when Phonegap (Cordova) has been loaded. If you rerun the application, Android may have not killed or garbage collected it, so it´s no sense to expect it to happen again until killed for sure and re run. Maybe you should call finish() in your activity pause code... But Look OUT! may not be what you wanted!

Comment: You should be using the `resume` event for actions that should fire after an app is brough forward from the background: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume

Comment: @eduayo: Uncaught ReferenceError: finish is not defined.

Comment: I don't think you should be adding you eventListener's within a doc ready. They have nothing to do with JQuery. They are Cordova events

Comment: OK, I deleted the surrounding `$(document).ready(function () {..});`, but it is still the same.

Comment: did you had any news on this? I encountered the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want such behavior, but you can kill the app on back press (or on finish). 
Calling `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` is just like a forcing a stop from the task manager.

Add this to your CordovaActivity and it should kill everything without any remains:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: No, as I said above, If I press back I leave the app, but it does not get killed. When I re-enter the app, it will not work unless I close it with the task manager. (Thats why I want that behaviour).

Comment: I'm aware of that - I'm saying you should explicitly call `killProcess()` when the user presses back to replicate the task manager's kill behavior. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, since I did not do any in Java on Android, could you tell me where to include the code snippet with `killProcess()`?

Comment: adding  `public void onBackPressed() {
     android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }` did not work either.

Comment: Where did you write the snippet? CordovaActivity?

Comment: Try to add `system.exit()` (see my edited answer). If you're positive this callback is in fact being called and it still doesn't work I'm afraid I'm stumped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61543/discussion-between-nitzanj-and-ferenjito).

Comment: I found the solution finally from somewhere else but I had to give the bounty anyways.

Comment: @Ferenjito what was your solution?

Comment: Ah, sorry, its like 5 months ago and I don't remember exactly... At least I remember it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `mainActivity.java` (whatever it is called in your project):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

Comment: public class MyApp extends CordovaActivity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    }
    
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }
}    <br/>      Unfortunately, it does not change anything.

Comment: it will still appear on the taskmanager list, but should be handled differently when you start it again

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the same thing, I used the backbutton event from cordova. You can find more about the backbutton event here: [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton). I can't find documentation about the app.exitApp() function but I do know it is only available for android and amazon-fireos.

See code snippet below, you only need to know when you want to exit, but you might know that from the document.location object or something. Hope it helps.

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (evt) {
    // replace this with some logic (maybe document.location) to now if you are on the main page or not
    if (true) {
        // Check if methods exists
        if (typeof navigator.app !== "undefined" && typeof navigator.app.exitApp !== "undefined") {
            evt.preventDefault();
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
    } else {
        history.back();
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not kill the app. It means, when I come back and re-enter the app, I have a problem.

Comment: Are you sure the app.exitApp() is executed? Because it should work (it does for me), deviceready is executed and I got my splashscreen on startup. Can you update your main post with the cordova version?

Comment: I am very sure that app.exitApp() is executed. If I drop that, the app simply does nothing when I leave it. I updated the main post, my Cordova Version is 3.5.0-0.2.6

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

In my_app_dir->config.xml add

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false" />
```

And below

> document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {...

add

```
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', function() {                     
       navigator.app.exitApp();
    }, false);
```

Afterwards open `cmd`, go to your project folder and run `cordova build android; cordova run --device android;`

Answer (score 0):

What works for me, the problem might be that the DOM is not ready when you add the event listener. And may be caused by a faster load due to the app being cached. Use a self executing function to add the event listener and you will be sure the DOM is loaded.

```
function domIsReady() {
    alert('DOM is ready')
}

function deviceIsReady() {
    alert('Device is Ready')
}

( function() {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            domIsReady();
        } else {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', domIsReady, false);
            } else {
                window.attachEvent('onload', domIsReady);
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceIsReady, true);
    }());
```